# Openshift - java.net.BindException: Permission denied

Tags: java, ftp, openshift, apache-commons

I am trying to create a simple java application that downloads a file from URL, stores the file and then uploads the file to FTP to store it.

I have a (local) working code that downloads the file to my local machine on C:\ and uses the local file to upload to FTP.

I would like to move this application to OpenShift and run it in Tomcat6 from there. This means that I have to change the C:\ drive reference to a directory in OpenShift. I referenced the "tmp" directory.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


    public class AppRun {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AppRun.class);

            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

            String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

            downloadFile(formattedDate);
            uploadFile(formattedDate);
        }

        // FILE DOWNLOAD
        public static void downloadFile(String formattedDate){

            Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AppRun.class);

            String sourceURL = "http://websiteURL/pdf/"+formattedDate+".pdf";
            String destinationLocation = "/tmp/"+formattedDate+".pdf";
            try {
                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(
                                new URL(sourceURL), 
                                new File(destinationLocation)
                                );
                log.warn("/tmp/"+formattedDate+".pdf downloaded successfully!" );
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { 
                log.error(e);
                log.error("Source URL : " + "http://websiteURL/pdf/"+formattedDate+".pdf" + " Destination URL : " + "/tmp/"+formattedDate+".pdf");
                System.out.println("No file found!");
            }

        }

        // FILE UPLOAD
        public static void uploadFile(String formattedDate){

            Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AppRun.class);

            FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
            FileInputStream fis = null;

            try {

                client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
                client.login("user", "pass");

                // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded         
                String originalFile = "/tmp/"+formattedDate+".pdf";
                fis = new FileInputStream(originalFile);

                //
                // Store file to server
                //
                String destinationFileName = formattedDate +".pdf";
                client.storeFile(destinationFileName, fis);
                log.warn("File " + formattedDate +".pdf uploaded successfully!");
                client.logout();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (fis != null) {
                        fis.close();
                    }
                    client.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

When I run the code, I can download the file but the upload part fails:

> /var/lib/openshift/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/cron/minutely/java:
>   2015-09-15 22:27:08 WARN  AppRun:41 - /tmp/20150915.pdf downloaded
>   successfully! 2015-09-15 22:27:09 ERROR AppRun:77 -
>   java.net.BindException: Permission denied java.net.BindException:
>   Permission denied
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
>           at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
>           at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.*openDataConnection*(FTPClient.java:797)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:633)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:624)
>           at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1976)
>           at AppRun.uploadFile(AppRun.java:72)
>           at AppRun.main(AppRun.java:25)

Any suggestions how to fix this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You need to configure the client for FTP PASSIVE mode.

Comment: @EJP - worked like a charm. Adding client.enterLocalPassiveMode(); after client.connect("ftp.domain.com"); fixed the issue. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll select it as a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the client for FTP PASSIVE mode.

Try adding `ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode()` after login.